# How can i scale a shape without scaling its pattern?

Tags: svg

I have an svg shape which uses a pattern. I want the pattern to NOT scale when i scale the shape.

Here's a fiddle with a minimal example, the bigger circle should show the pattern like the smaller one:

http://jsfiddle.net/cTMrQ/6/

```
<svg style="position: absolute" width="100%" height="100%" version="1.1" baseProfile="full" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xmlns:ev="http://www.w3.org/2001/xml-events">
    <defs>
        <pattern id="checkerPattern" patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse" x="0" y="0" width="4" height="4">
            <image x="0" y="0" xlink:href="http://inwonderland.at/new/lines.png" width="4" height="4" />
        </pattern>
        <circle fill="url(#checkerPattern)" id="c" cx="50" cy="50" r="50" />
    </defs>
    <use x="100" y="100" xlink:href="#c" />
    <use x="200" y="100" xlink:href="#c" transform="scale(2)" />
</svg>
```

In the end the shape will be a complex path and the image in the pattern will be a scan of a piece of paper, so just drawing a bigger circle instead of scaling it won't work.

**Update**

To clarify what i want, here are two images:

this is what it looks like, no matter what i try, when i scale the shape:
http://inwonderland.at/new/ihave.png

this is what i want:
http://inwonderland.at/new/iwant.png

i want the background image (bitmap image) to always have its natural size.

Comment: I don't get anything when I try to display this.

Comment: hmm, works for me in firefox, chrome and internet explorer (all current versions). maybe try this direct svg link? http://inwonderland.at/new/test.svg

Comment: Ok, just the one tool that won't display it, works with firefox. Don't know why.

Comment: I think this can be done easily with `patternTransform`.  You just have to set the pattern transform to the INVERSE of the view scale. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/patternTransform

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't get what you want using a pattern, the transform always happens after the fill, and you can't just move the pattern fill into a  wrapper either. My suggestion is to use a filter and apply the filter on a  wrapper - like so:

```
<svg style="position: absolute" width="100%" height="100%" version="1.1" baseProfile="full" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xmlns:ev="http://www.w3.org/2001/xml-events">
    <defs>

 <circle fill="url(#checkerPattern)" id="c1" cx="50" cy="50" r="50" />

 <filter id="linepattern" x="0%" y="0%" height="100%" width="100%">
 <feImage xlink:href="http://inwonderland.at/new/lines.png" result="pattern" width="4" height="4"/>
   <feTile/>
   <feComposite operator="in" in2="SourceGraphic"/>
      </filter>
    </defs>

    <use filter="url(#linepattern)" x="100" y="100" xlink:href="#c1" />

    <use filter="url(#linepattern)" x="200" y="100" xlink:href="#c1" transform="scale(2)" />

    <g filter="url(#linepattern)"> 
    <use x="50" y="100" xlink:href="#c1" transform="scale(2)" />
</g> 
</svg>
```

Answer (score 3):

**Using viewport**

1:1 no zoom

```
<svg width="800" height="400" viewBox="0 0 800 400">
```

2:1 zoom double size

```
<svg width="800" height="400" viewBox="0 0 400 200">
```

The following elements can use the viewBox attribute

```
<svg>
<symbol>
<image>
<marker>
<pattern>
<view>
```

viewbox is fully animatable; and you can zoom into any center point.

```
 <animate attributeName="viewBox" begin="1s" dur="1s"
           values="0 0 600 400; 250 180 300 200" fill="freeze" />
```

**Transform a parent tag**

Yes an SVG can be a child element but more commonly shapes made with multible tags are placed inside a group tag.

Transform scale can be used with tags which are parents IE the group tag.

```
<g transform="scale(1.5)">
/* draw your shape inside the g tag */
<use x="100" y="100" xlink:href="#c" />
<use x="200" y="100" xlink:href="#c" />
</g>
```

So using your above example scale the shape in a parent tag.

**Update**

To scale image but not patterns in other words move patterns, or icons, on background image that scales.

```
<g transform="scale(2)">
/* draw your shape inside the g tag */
<use x="100" y="100" xlink:href="#c" transform="scale(.5)" />
<use x="200" y="100" xlink:href="#c" transform="scale(.5)"/>
</g>
```

**Update full svg**

I had to move things around a bit, One full size, (lets call it a map), with an overlay of 1 half size map in the upper left corner. setting the full screen to render between 0 and max of 600. Setting a viewport the same but with the width set to 300 scales it down. I do need to double the radius for this example of scaling.

```
<svg viewBox="0 0 600 600" style="position: absolute" width="100%" height="100%" version="1.1" baseProfile="full" 

xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xmlns:ev="http://www.w3.org/2001/xml-events">
    <defs>
        <pattern id="checkerPattern" patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse" x="0" y="0" width="4" height="4">
            <image x="0" y="0" xlink:href="http://inwonderland.at/new/lines.png" width="4" height="4" />
        </pattern>
        <circle fill="url(#checkerPattern)" id="c" cx="50" cy="50" r="50" />
        <circle fill="url(#checkerPattern)" id="c2" cx="50" cy="50" r="100" />
    </defs>
<use x="100" y="100" xlink:href="#c" transform="scale(.5)"/>
<use x="200" y="100" xlink:href="#c" transform="scale(1)"/>
<rect width="600" height="600" style="fill: none; stroke: black;" />

<svg viewBox="0 0 600 600" width="300" height="300"  x="300">
<use x="100" y="100" xlink:href="#c2" transform="scale(.5)"/>
<use x="200" y="100" xlink:href="#c2" transform="scale(1)"/>
<rect width="600" height="600" style="fill: none; stroke: black;" />
</svg>
</svg>
```

This example is scaled using the same circle pattern. The radius does not need to be changed here because the location is not in the tag being scaled. I'm making use of svg tags here but other tags can be used.

```
<svg viewBox="0 0 600 600" style="position: absolute" width="100%" height="100%" version="1.1" baseProfile="full" 

xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xmlns:ev="http://www.w3.org/2001/xml-events">
    <defs>
        <pattern id="checkerPattern" patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse" x="0" y="0" width="4" height="4">
            <image x="0" y="0" xlink:href="http://inwonderland.at/new/lines.png" width="4" height="4" />
        </pattern>
        <circle fill="url(#checkerPattern)" id="c" r="50" cx="50" cy="50" />
    </defs>


<svg x="100" y="100"><use xlink:href="#c" transform="scale(.5)"/></svg>
<svg x="200" y="100"><use xlink:href="#c" transform="scale(1)"/></svg>
<rect width="600" height="600" style="fill: none; stroke: black;" />

<svg viewBox="0 0 600 600" width="300" height="300"  x="300">
<svg x="100" y="100"><use xlink:href="#c" transform="scale(1)"/></svg>
<svg x="200" y="100"><use xlink:href="#c" transform="scale(2)"/></svg>
<rect width="600" height="600" style="fill: none; stroke: black;" />
</svg>
</svg>
```

Comment: sorry i don't get it, no matter what i do to scale the shape, as soon as it is scaled, the pattern is scaled too (in the example i want exactly one pixel black, one pixel white alternating, no matter how big the shape is)

Comment: ok, maybe i'm stupid, but even when i read your edits i can't figure out how to do it. the pattern ALWAYS scales. maybe if you could give a full working example? i want to resize (either through transform or viewbox or whatever) a shape (path) which is filled by the pattern and as the shape gets bigger, you can see more tiles of the pattern, because the pattern does not scale with the shape.

Comment: @rossi I've made an update with two examples, hope if solves the issues.

Comment: If you want to scale part of the image and not specific elements you must in some way tell the browser what elements are not being scaled. In the 2nd example we are reducing the entire canvas by 1/2 and doubling the size of the elements that do not scale.

Comment: i see scaled background on those examples. i have updated the question to clarify what i want. thanks for your patience btw. =)

Comment: The texture is not in a scale-able format. You need to draw a circle with a bigger radius - first full svg example; id="c" and id="c2"

Comment: well i know that i can draw a bigger circle, but the shapes i want to draw in the end are complex paths...

Comment: Scaling a pattern with a texture from an raster image will scale the raster image; It does that by design. Its the wrong tool. You need to look at clippath http://sawyerhollenshead.com/writing/using-svg-clippath/ and masking.

Comment: yeah... i wanted to avoid that because of other things becoming more complicated this way, but i guess this is the answer.

Comment: i cannot really accept this as an answer though? i'm new to stackoverflow, what do i do now? =)