# SVG background pattern without scaling or masking

Tags: css, svg, background

I have several countrymaps in SVG format. The countries are made up of various regions. Each region is a path in the SVG and each region (depending on the dataset) has a certain pattern. The pattern is filled like this (simplified):

```
<defs>
  <pattern id="pattern4"
           x="0" y="0" width="100" height="100"
           patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse" >
      <rect x="0" y="0" width="50" height="50" style="fill: black"/>
  </pattern>
</defs>
```

This works fine, however, the maps are gigantic and so are the `viewbox`. The pattern above is shown as small dots, not even squares. It does work though, but the problem is that I need a legend with corresponding patterns. This I can't seem to solve, because the pattern above is scaled by the viewport of the SVG. I can somehow scale the pattern in the legend, but since the maps are responsive, it often doesn't even come close to eachother. Making the legend useless.

I tried masking, but since I am using several very large SVG-maps on the same webpage, this seems to give (memory?) issues on older computers / browsers. I tried using image backgrounds instead of SVG's but without luck.

I made a very simple [JSfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/a6e1ug0s/2/) to show the problem. All three squares have the same pattern, but they look different caused by the viewbox;

Is there any way to get even patterns? It works but masking and regular images, but this fails on a lot of PC's and mobiles, thus that isn't a solution. Any other direction is welcome as well.

Comment: One way to get constant size patterns is to fill your shape using a filter (an feImage referencing an external SVG (or a SVG fragment if you just want Chrome) that has your pattern at the dimensions you want.) This answer may help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21208673/how-can-i-scale-a-shape-without-scaling-its-pattern/21212273#21212273

Comment: Thank you  for your reply. This might work, but I don't think I can control the pattern with CSS right? Since the fill should be dynamic, I am now using a class to project the right pattern on pageload. I made a very simple example here: https://jsfiddle.net/t5k0x4bu/ Is it possible to overwrite the `checker2` with `checker` using CSS?

Comment: Yes, but you need to use the filter: CSS property not the fill: CSS property. (You can't use a filter as a fill directly)

Comment: I guess I am close. I can switch between patterns by using a class, however, the pattern now ignores te border of the path resulting in a square. See https://jsbin.com/wocaludevu/2/edit?html,css,js,output If you replace the current filter-1 class in the path with for example fill-1 or fill-2 you'll see the difference. Is there any way to just show the path filled with the filter?

Answer (score 1):

Use an filter/feImage to do a fixed size pattern. Clip the generated pattern to the source path by adding a feComposite/in.

Filters don't support a patternUnits property - please delete those.

Here is a minimal working example based on your code above.

```css
.filter-2 {
  filter: url("#filter-2");
}
```

```html
<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" viewBox="0 0 2960 3464" width="100%" height="100%">

<defs>
    <filter id="filter-2">
     <feImage xlink:href="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/7/70/Checkerboard_pattern.svg/500px-Checkerboard_pattern.svg.png" result="pattern" width="100" height="100"/><feTile/>
   <feComposite operator="in" in2="SourceGraphic"/>
  </filter>
  </defs>
  
  <g id="Layer_36">
    <path class="filter-2 st0 zuid-limburg" d="M1830.37,3030.01c4.47,1.42,6.65-0.94,8.56-4.64c1.88-3.65,2.75-8.11,7.69-11.15
        c1.19,7.82,2.57,14.86,3.23,21.96c0.36,3.87,1.3,6.13,5.54,6.52c1.88,0.18,3.61,1.94,5.5,2.14c5.74,0.61,6.94,4.61,6.96,9.15
        c0.04,11.94,0.71,12.57,12.12,9.7c0.96-0.24,1.92-0.53,2.87-0.79c1.08,3.83,2.37,7.61,3.2,11.49c0.66,3.1,2.01,6.52,4.35,7.58
        c5.74,2.59,8.6,6.66,11.52,12.15c4.04,7.6,5.72,14.68,1.6,21.62c-1.99,3.35-5.96,6.78-2.7,10.66c3.47,4.13,7.99,0.85,12.01-0.3
        c3.26-0.93,6.36-2.32,8.59-4.86c3.54-4.03,8.23-5.21,13.12-6.47c4.98-1.28,9.05-0.91,12.39,3.48c3.01,3.96,6.67,3.68,11.51,2.77
        c9.73-1.82,19.74-2.36,29.66-2.87c5.63-0.28,7.07,1.55,5.27,6.49c-3.02,8.33-4.68,17.47-13.21,24.01
        c8.15,4.42,6.2,12.48,7.47,19.19c0.95,4.99,2.5,7.74,7.52,8.93c4.83,1.14,9.39,3.48,14.23,4.6c3.42,0.8,6.2,0.99,6.81,5.54
        c0.54,4.07,5.04,3.98,7.28,3.02c6.98-2.97,12.09,0.89,18.59,3.55c-5.39,7.68-8.71,15.66-10.63,24.48
        c-1.49,6.85-0.66,12.71,3.58,17.68c4.93,5.77,4.84,12.59,1.59,17.58c-4.37,6.73-6.51,13.61-7.08,21.42
        c-4.19-0.29-9.04-1.39-10.25-3.9c-3.42-7.04-6.71-4.27-10.65-1.27c-3.53,2.69-8.45,1.84-11.95,4.74c-2.67,2.21-7.85,1.5-8.28,6.2
        c-0.48,5.17-1.9,10.61,1.57,15.41c2.6,3.59,3.69,7.28,3.44,11.96c-0.49,9.21-7.92,13.07-13.04,18.72c-1.25,1.38-3.06,1.09-4.51-0.1
        c-1.29-1.06-2.51-2.19-3.72-3.33c-7.38-6.95-10.07-4.31-13.54,3.85c-1.56,3.66-0.37,6.68,3.42,8.06
        c5.59,2.04,9.18,6.07,12.66,10.67c3.67,4.84,9.1,7.73,14.66,10.11c4.69,2.02,5.77,4.99,3.17,9.49c-1.15,1.99-1.97,4.23-2.56,6.46
        c-0.76,2.86,1.18,6.37-0.86,8.71c-2.55,2.93-6.9,2.32-10.29,2.72c-7.93,0.93-16.36,3.44-22.7-5.23c-2.33-3.19-7.32-4.43-11.88-3.16
        c-7.99,2.23-16.16,4.07-23.07,9.01c-2.67,1.91-4.88,3.33-7.55-0.17c-2.3-3.01-5.25-1.3-8.18-0.52c-5.69,1.52-8.7-0.63-9.58-6.37
        c-0.2-1.31,0.02-2.69-0.22-3.98c-1.13-6.15-2.31-6.52-8.62-4.29c-7.47,2.64-14.97,5.09-20.04,11.13c-2.85-0.7-2.47-2.64-3-4.12
        c-1.75-4.83-3.11-5.52-6.89-2.61c-3.46,2.67-6.74,4.74-11.3,5.62c-9.99,1.91-9.88,2.31-15.79-6.47c-2.29-3.4-3.77-7.95-9.63-6.12
        c-1.62,0.51-2.96-1.32-3.59-2.92c-0.86-2.16-1.57-4.39-2.26-6.61c-2.24-7.26-7.51-9.24-11.69-3.47
        c-5.72,7.9-15.87,12.78-16.87,24.05c-0.22,2.46-2.4,2.97-4.58,2.38c-2.63-0.71-5.03-1.97-6.56-4.28c-1.74-2.63-3.06-2.4-5.51-0.49
        c-4.17,3.25-10.13,3.06-14.24,6.77c-0.62,0.56-1.9,0.53-2.88,0.51c-2.77-0.06-5.43-0.93-7.07-3.14c-1.98-2.66-0.1-5.21,1.43-7.26
        c3.54-4.77,8.12-8.67,9.8-14.84c1.28-4.71,2.16-8.64-1.21-13.07c-3.57-4.7-4.71-9.71-0.54-15.53c3.58-4.99,0.62-10.06-5.73-11.88
        c-7.39-2.12-13.66-7.17-21.53-8.08c-2.38-0.28-2.57-2.48-3.09-4.51c-1.72-6.73-4.05-13.25-7.96-19.08
        c-3.94-5.86-2.04-12.28-1.65-18.48c0.39-6.13,3.7-11.7,3.87-17.92c0.06-1.94,1.49-2.91,3-3.63c3.01-1.43,5.68-3.98,8.6-4.86
        c8.33-2.52,13.26-8.29,18.43-14.76c3.54-4.43,5.94-8.3,5.88-14.1c-0.09-8.29,3.78-10.59,11.37-7.49
        c6.74,2.75,10.45,1.07,10.29-5.98c-0.2-8.75,2.94-15.48,9.02-21.25c2.26-2.14,3.81-4.85,4.39-7.72c0.98-4.86,2.71-8.61,7.53-10.92
        c3.99-1.9,3.58-5.35,0.94-8.28c-2.6-2.88-5.16-6.77-9.95-3.71c-2.2,1.41-3.58,4.04-6.38,4.62c-3.03,0.63-6.1,0.75-8.27-1.94
        c-1.98-2.45-1.57-5.5,0.42-7.33c6.46-5.91,7.78-16.33,17.35-19.46c1.99-0.65,2.77-2.78,3.68-4.56c0.91-1.78,1.39-3.94,2.71-5.32
        c6.75-7.12,10.11-15.17,8.64-25.17c-0.51-3.48,2.85-5.86,4.28-8.82c3.04-6.31,2.3-8.43-4.21-11.62c-7.6-3.72-7.86-4.47-3.39-11.82
        c4.19-6.9,7.61-13.88,7.28-22.4c-0.2-5.28,1.73-6.2,7.04-3.72C1821.44,3029.78,1825.54,3031.69,1830.37,3030.01z"></path>
</g>

</svg>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your effort, appreciated! Your code works great, however, now i'd still have the sizing issue I started off with I guess. When you scale the screen, the SVG get's smaller and the pattern resizes with it. Is there something to do about that?